# Xcode new build system uses wrong build configuration set in scheme

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a large app with multiple schemes and configurations. Ever since I use the new build system, Xcode shows info off the wrong build configuration.

I have 10 configurations and 10 schemes.
If I select scheme4 it should use configuration4 but it doesn't. It always uses the first configuration that is listed in Project -> Info.

Every time I go to my Target -> Info, it should show info of the current build configuration settings of that scheme but it doesn't. If I switch back to the old build system it works like intented ...

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with the legacy build system for now. The new build system has a couple of showstopper bugs and should not have been promoted to the default yet.

Comment: Yes indeed, I started a new project with the new build system. Added a scheme, with a build configuration that has a specific bundle identifier so I can see in my Target -> Info what the bundle identifier is for the current scheme and with the new build system it still shows the wrong one.

Comment: Be sure to file a bug with Apple!